# Layered Architecture - Repository and reflection

Tags: java, architecture

I am currently using Layered Architecture in my (small) project and thought about extending my BaseRepository (the one the class-specific repositories inherit from) using reflection for the insert/update/delete methods.

My `BaseRepository.java` looks like this:

```
public  abstract class BaseRepository<CLASS extends BaseDomain<CLASS>>{

}
```

Where `BaseDomain` is just:

```
public class BaseDomain<CLASS extends BaseDomain<CLASS>> {
    private Long id;

    //getters setts etc.
}
```

Now my problem is in the deleteById method in the BaseRepository:

```
 public  int deleteById(Connection connection, Long id) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement delete= connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM ? WHERE id = ?");
    delete.setObject(1, entity) //heres the problem, where do I get entity from?
    delete.setObject(2, id);

    return 0;
}
```

My specific repository extends the Base one like this:

```
public class UserRepository extends BaseRepository<User>{

}
```

How do I get the `User` class in the `BaseRepository` so I can use it in the delete/update etc. methods?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don’t think you need a connection object in the method arguments list.

Answer (score 1):

How about making the entity be a param to the BaseRepository constructor.

EDIT:

```
public class UserRepository extends BaseRepository<User>{

    public static final String ENTITY = "users";        

    public UserRepository(){
        super(ENTITY);
    }    

}
```

Comment: Does that mean every time you need to create a new Repository instance?  And do you need that entity instance when you do querying?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way I can think but I haven’t tried is to pass the entity class type to the `BaseRepository`.

```
private final Class<CLASS> entityType;
public BaseRepository(Class<CLASS> entityType) {
  this.entityType = entityType;
// do your stuff
}
```

To find the right table to operate according to the entity class type. Could be by convention like most of Ruby ORMs do, say, if the entity type is `User`, then you can operate against `users` or `user` or whatever the convention is.

Or could have a object to provide the configuration to `BaseRepository`